# setting useLegacyAuth=1 in Workbench 6.0

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have been trying the `useLegacyAuth=1` setting in the advanced option box, unfortunately its not holding the line. This line disappear immediately after I connect!! any clues please?
Workbench version: 6.0.7

I can connect to the server (by checking the disable secure auth checkbox), but when I do a backup its keep failing. Please help.

Answer (score 5):

try to add `"useLegacyAuth=1"` in "Others" area, located in "Advanced" pill on connection configuration. (with quotes)

Comment: @MnemonicFlow
You need to add quotes around that parameter, I have edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

In advanced pane, check the box *use the old authentication protocol*[image]