# MYSQL ERROR 2049 (HY000): Connection using old (pre-4.1.1) authentication protocol ref used (client option 'secure_auth' enabled)?

Tags: authentication, mysql, mysql-workbench

I have seen several solutions to this error on stackoverflow, including adding `useLegacyAuth=1` to the Advanced options box in the connection settings dialog. My problem is everytime I add this into the options box, it never saves the addition I made.  I will test connection with this, and it works, but once I exit out and attempt to do a mysqldump (my purpose and through which I discovered this error), it gives me the error above again.

Does anyone know why this setting doesn't save or how to have it save?  I would like to solve the problem this way as it seems easiest and I can't change the root password to the database I am trying to connect to (another potential fix).

Anyone know another solution to fixing the error below in case there isnt above?

```
ERROR 2049 (HY000): Connection using old (pre-4.1.1) authentication protocol ref used (client option 'secure_auth' enabled)
```

Comment: Related Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913016/setting-uselegacyauth-1-in-workbench-6-0

Comment: mysqldump is a different tool with own settings. If you start it manually you have to pass in the legacy auth setting manually. Is it however started from MySQL Workbench (i.e. from the dump and restore section) that should happen automatically.

Comment: Subscribe to the bug here: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70023&thanks=3&notify=195

Comment: The bug report is at http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=75425 and for ideas for workarounds, see https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=100831